# zkcm configuration fails, can't find gmpxx.h

Tags: macos, gmp, zkcm

I'm trying to get zkcm up and running on my system (Mac OS X 10.11.3). I've installed gmp just fine (using  `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx`), and mpfr installed easily once I told it where to find gmp (/usr/local/include).

However, zkcm isn't installing as easily. It is also able to find the gmp.h file (using `./configure --with-gmp-include=/usr/local/include`), but even though I can see gmpxx.h is right there, the configuration fails with

```
checking /usr/local/include/gmp.h usability... yes
checking /usr/local/include/gmp.h presence... yes
checking for /usr/local/include/gmp.h... yes
checking /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h usability... no
checking /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h presence... no
checking for /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h... no
configure: error: not found.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I've tried re-installing gmp several times, to no avail.

I've gone through other similar questions, but I could only find information directing me to what I've already done. I'm using the latest libraries for all three. How can I properly direct zkcm to gmpxx.h?

## **Edit**

All of the config.log text with "gmpxx.h":

```
configure:3331: checking /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h usability
configure:3331: g++ -c -g -O2  conftest.cpp >&5
In file included from conftest.cpp:53:
/usr/local/include/gmpxx.h:43:10: error: 'gmp.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <gmp.h>
     ^~~~~~~
     "gmp.h"
1 error generated.
configure:3331: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE__USR_LOCAL_INCLUDE_GMP_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include </usr/local/include/gmpxx.h>
configure:3331: result: no
configure:3331: checking for /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h
configure:3331: result: no
configure:3338: error: not found.
```

Comment: `file /usr/local/include/gmpxx.h` says it exists? Does the file `config.log` contain more details about the failure to detect gmpxx?

Comment: The file definitely exists. I've added the relevant text from config.log to my original question - I'm not sure what to make of it though.

Comment: zkcm seems to have a weird configure. It should `#include <gmpxx.h>` with `-I/usr/local/include`, not try to be clever (that seldom works) with `#include </usr/local/include/gmpxx.h>`...

Comment: Thanks, so what's the fix for that then? I looked for a confdefs.h, but didn't see one in the zkcm files.

Comment: The way forward would be to write to the zkcm developers (never heard of that project) and ask them about it. Temporarily, you could heed the compiler message, edit gmpxx.h and replace `<gmp.h>` with `"gmp.h"`. You could also try defining an environment variable `CGLAGS=-I/usr/local/include`. But please don't skip the part about telling the zkcm developers.

Comment: That was supposed to be `CFLAGS` not `CGLAGS`... Or maybe `CXXFLAGS`.